# html display differences when viewed under different resolutions

Tags: html, layout, screen-resolution

I'm encountering layout changes when I view my website in different environments (my laptop and PC). I'm running the same version of `firefox (28.0)`, and both are under windows XP. I find that the `divs` begin lower on the laptop than the PC, forcing me to set `top:-40px` to align it to the top for the laptop, but of course this then hides a bit of the top one on the laptop).

The resolution is set to the same on both, though the PC screen is much physically wider, and I've been through the settings and both appear to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive stylesheets.
Add sth like this in place where U are adding stylesheets to your html site ().

```
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "style000.css" media="screen and (min-width: 501px) and    (max-width: 1300px)" type = "text/css" />
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "style00.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1301px) and  (max-width: 1421px)" type = "text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1421px) and (max-width: 2000px)"  href="style0.css" />
```

Choose suitable resolutions, create as many stylesheets as U need.

Comment: great, thanks for that - I'll try it (later next week, once home) best wishes, paul